# Instagram: Checking profile names if they are in my own follower list

Tags: php, instagram, form-submit

My idea is to build a form which checks if the typed profile name is or is not in the follower list of my instagram page. Just a simple form, something like:

```
<form action="something.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="profile_name"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

Since the Instagram API is almost deprecated I was wondering if there is a way to get a follower list...or other ways to get a "true" or "false" in the end.

Comment: You can write a parser...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ["Instagram's private API"](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)

There is a function to [get followers](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Request/People.php) (line 360)

Comment: I will try it out and see what I will achieve! Thanks alot!